# running PowerShell cmd with pipeline in cmd prompt

Tags: powershell, prompt, select-string

I want to run the cmd `select-string` in cmd prompt to find some string recursive.

But it can't work while the cmd have the pipeline(|) character, and it will work by running the cmd in the powershell prompt.

[image]

The Chinese error info is:

```
'select-string' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone know how to fix this?
Make the pipeline sense in the cmd prompt or use `select-string` to find string recursive.

I want to make it work in my case, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are calling the pipeline object of select-string in cmd prompt and not directly in powershell. Open Powershell and try it, it will work.

Comment: Such as the picture, run in powershell it will work, but I only want to run the command in cmd prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535190/running-powershell-cmd-with-tube-in-cmd-prompt#comment93938081_53535190), you need to use pipe in PowerShell, not in cmd. You can do it like this:

```
powershell "Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern 'something something'"
```

---

**Note**: Of course it's just a workaround, I'd still suggest to just run PowerShell cmdlets in PowerShell, not in cmd. It can save you from the headache of troubleshooting non-working code.

Comment: Thanks, I run this command in the salt cmd.run, like this: salt -G 'os:windows' cmd.run 'powershell "get-childitem -recurse -path c:\ -include *.ini | select-string -pattern 'some string'"', now it works well, is there has some other way to call the powershell by using salt cmd.run?

Comment: @VictorLee I'm not a SaltStack expert but usually you can run PowerShell scripts using `powershell.exe C:\path\to\script.ps1`. If you do so, remember to set appropriate ExecutionPolicy (see [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2702/setting-the-powershell-execution-policy/)).